# DC motor speed control using Pmos

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-analysis, dc-motor, power-electronics

[image]

I am trying to control dc motor(12V,1A) using npn transistor(BC547) and p channel mosfet(FQP7P06).PWM signal from MCU switches transistor which switches mosfet(Functioning ok).But in that case too much heat is generated across mosfet which is intollerable.Pmos has a rating of -7A,-60V. How can i solve the generated heat issue?

Comment: Can you provide the Q2 trace?  There might be high switching losses that can be reduced by snubbing.  Using a schottky diode will include matters as mentioned by @Andy aka

Answer (score 1):

The p channel mosfet you have chosen has an on resistance of about 0.4 ohms. If your motor current is (say) 4 amps, this will produce a power dissipation of 6.4 watts. It's likely that you should be choosing a mosfet with lower on-resistance or use a heat sink.

You also have the mosfet upside down in your schematic but I suspect this is just a diagrammatical error.

Your motor peak current could be a lot higher than the 1 amp you state when driving a mechanical load. Also, if your pwm frequency is too high there could be significant extra load produced by your motor that you may not of accounted for.

You haven't specified the fly back diode and a poor choice here could mean more current. For instance, a 1N400x diode has a very poor reverse recovery time of about 30 us - in other words it takes this length of time to revert from forward conduction (fly back) to reverse blocking.

Comment: Here I am using Schottky Barrier diode 1N5817 as a flyback diode

Comment: mosfet upside down in schematic just a diagrammatical error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider the following:

1. Use another P-MOSFET with lower \$R_{DS(on)}\$ and better thermal behaviour. FQP7P06 has a whooping 0.4 Ohm ON resistance and 3.75 ºC/W juntion-to-sink thermal resistance. Consider instead [IRF4905](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf4905pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e329b1197e), rated at 0.02 mOhm ON resistance and 1.25 ºC/W juntion-to-sink thermal resistance. Also, use a proper heatsink to take full profit of the lower junction-to-sink characteristics.
2. Use a push-pull topology for the MOSFET gate driver. This will reduce the time the MOSFET spends in the ohmic region while switching OFF. While in the ohmic region it dissipates a lot of power, which adds up to other problems (high \$R_{DS(on)}\$, high juntion-to-sink thermal resistance, etc.). Right now, when the input PWM signal goes low, the capacitor at the MOSFET gate has to charge +15V through a 500 Ohm resistor, which can result in an RC too slow.
3. As said by Andy Aka, a slow recovery flyback diode can also add-up to the problem. Choosing an adequate flyback diode here is not a trivial matter: it will depend on your PWM frequency and the switching behaviour of all the other components in the circuit (including the motor). With that information in your hand you'll have to take into account:

   - Recovery time -> must be compatible with your PWM frequency.
   - Peak current -> must be compatible with the reactive energy stored in the motor that.
   - Average current -> must be compatible with the peak current and the PWM frequency.

Check whether a [1N5818](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88525/1n5817.pdf) suits your needs or not.